# Unsupervised clustering with a categorical with tens of thousands of levels

Tags: r, clustering, unsupervised-learning, many-categories, tf-idf

I need to perform a clustering analysis of a medical claims dataset to identify anomalous healthcare providers.

My dataset contains a variable called `diagnosis code` which captures the ICD-10 diagnosis code attached to a claim. This code is used by physicians and other healthcare providers to classify and code all diagnoses, symptoms and procedures associated with a visit to a healthcare professional.

In the ICD-10 system, there are between 69K-70K unique codes that can be used and this becomes a real problem for one-hot encoding.

I am keen to understand if there are approaches for handling categorical variables with this many levels. I realize that I can convert these specific ICD-10 codes to a higher level i.e. N18.1 (Chronic kidney disease, stage 1) can be rolled up to a higher level but this still leaves thousands of codes which still means thousands of columns in my data frame.

I've been researching ways to reduce the number of input features and one approach I read about (@olooney) was to use TF-IDF where the ICD-10 codes for each provider are considered words and every provider is considered a document.

This is a cool approach but I don't think it will help me reduce the number of variables in my feature space, rather it will convert each ICD-10 codes from a 1 or 0 to a weight depending on how important it is still leaving me with potentially tens of thousands of columns.

Please shout if there's a simpler or more sophisticated approach to dealing with this kind of problem.

Comment: In what way are the providers anomalous?

Comment: Hi @Paul, some providers could be over prescribing the same product too often. Take a general physician, the average physician may prescribe over a 1 year period say 150 unique products both low and high cost whereas an anomalous provider may prescribe 10 unique high cost products which may need to be investigated. The ICD-10 feature is interesting as it could tie to the provider's taxonomy i.e. lots of oncology ICD10 codes for an oncologist is reasonable but for a gynecologists raises some questions.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a strong relationship between the diagnosis code and what is prescribed?  I would think you would do the analysis diagnosis as a by-group.  For each diagnosis, you look at typical patterns of what is prescribed, and the anomalies would be the outliers for the prescriptions for each diagnosis.

Comment: There likely will be some diagnosis codes which will be too sparse to do the analysis, but that's going to be an issue no matter what.

Comment: You will have to bin diagnoses anyway, for if almost each patient has its own unique diagnosis, no analysis is possible.